problem with the connection between the server and the iOS device in .net maui
I'm working on Maui.
I have a problem with the connection between the server and the iOS device.
It works well on Android devices, but I’ve tried everything possible on iOS without success.
I can open the Link on Safari, without any problems.
The server works fine, HTTPS also works fine, and I’ve tried using Plist (NSAppTransportSecurity, etc.), manual configuration, and more for iOS, but I still get the message:
‘The Server seems to be Offline’.
It works when the IOS Device ist not in the same Network and is connected via VPN.
It also woks on Remote MAC IOS Simulator.
This is my pList:
<?XML Version="1.0" Encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
<array>
<integer>1</integer>
<integer>2</integer>
</array>
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
<string>arm64</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Assets.xcassets/appicon.appiconset</string>
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
<string>11.0</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
<key>mytestwebsite.com</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
<key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
<true/>
<key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
<true/>
</dict>
</dict>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>myBundleID</string>
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>myProjectName</string>
</dict>
</dict>
</plist>


Where is the relevant code?  How specifically are you trying to connect to the server?

Here is the code line:
try
{
sessionId = await Service.Api.GetSessionIdAsync();
successful = sessionId != 0;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}

For Android and even Mac it works

Please do not post code in comments.  Is GetSessionIdAsync your code, or something from a library?

from library
the thing is With a private network from the server, I can’t see my data, but with a public network, I can. I still have a connection for Safari and others, it’s just in iOS that I don’t know what’s wrong. My server is also HTTPS, and I’ve checked everything like firewall , ....

It sounds like a networking issue, with the info provided its impossible to provide more help

i also tryed VPN

Do you use the third-party Nuget  for the connection?

Yea, i also tryed VPN for private server its also the same, but with vpn and public netwerk i can see infos. i think its microsoft problem unknown problem idk.

its important to me ,see infos with private network(Server Network),
cause public server is not safe .
